# Send an alternative email to an anonymous user who placed an order

Tags: emails, commerce, notifications

I have 2 cases:

A registered and logged in user who gets an email after he placed an order. In that email he gets the token [message:message-commerce-order:view-url] where he can view his order.

An anonymous user gets the same email but: But I'd like to delete the token [message:message-commerce-order:view-url] because an anonymous user can't see that page because he needs to log in.

How do I send an alternative mail to anonymous users after they place an order?

Comment: Have you tried to change the relevant rule?

Comment: What version of Drupal and what shopping cart are you using. This would greatly help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look to the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to accomplish this, though a lot depends on how you are managing orders (Commerce module?).

If using Rules you could set **conditions** for user role to determine which email they get.